# How to make a field of a document a primary key in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

So I want to prevent a document with same `email` field to get added into the firestore database.This is automatic in authentication but not in firestore.

This is my base function:

```
const register = async () => {
        await addDoc(userCollectionRef, {username: userName, email: newUser, password: registerPassword})
        try {
          const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUser, registerPassword);
          console.log(user);
        } 
        catch(e) {
          console.log(e.message);
          console.log(e.code);
          if((e.code) === "auth/email-already-in-use"){
            window.alert("Email already registered");
          }
        }
        
    }
```

What should i do to make email field a primary key?

Comment: You should write in firebase after creating a user with email and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write in firebase after creating a user with email and password.

```
const register = async () => {
        
        try {
          const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUser, registerPassword).then(() => await addDoc(userCollectionRef, {username: userName, email: newUser, password: registerPassword})) ;
          console.log(user);
        } 
        catch(e) {
          console.log(e.message);
          console.log(e.code);
          if((e.code) === "auth/email-already-in-use"){
            window.alert("Email already registered");
          }
        }
        
    }
```

As Frank mentioned above, there is no way, to achieve your purpose, you can make use of the Firebase `createUser` function in the sdk. If the user is already created, it will throw an error, and your write document to firebase will not be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't have the concept of a primary key. The closest equivalent is the document ID.

If you want to specify your own document ID, use `setDoc` with a document reference instead of `addDoc`:

```
const userDocRef = doc(userCollectionRef, newUser)
await setDoc(docRef, {username: userName, email: newUser, password: registerPassword})
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [writing a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9).